# Regex Error in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to select cities starting with a,e, i,o,u and ending with a,e, i,o,u in MySQL.(Case not matters)

Query1

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU]' and CITY REGEXP '[AEIOU]$';
```

Query2

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU]*[AEIOU]$';
```

Why Query2 is giving me an error although Query1 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first query, you only fetch entries that start or end with vowels. The second one only matches entries that start with 0 or more vowels and end with a vowel (so, you will get results like `a` or `Aou` only).

You might try using

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU].*[AEIOU]$'
                                                    ^^
```

The `.*` pattern matches any 0+ chars, as many as possible, so it will matching any string that starts AND ends with a vowel.

However, `WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU]' and CITY REGEXP '[AEIOU]$'` fetches entries only consisting of 1 vowel, and the above will not match a record like `A` (one-vowel string). To match those use an optional group:

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU](.*[AEIOU])?$'
                                                    ^         ^^
```

Here, `(...)?` is a capturing group (MySQL regex does not support non-capturing ones) that matches a sequence of patterns *1 or 0 times* (due to the `?` quantifier).

A couple of notes on the regex:

- `^[AEIOU].*[AEIOU]$` - matches a whole string that starts and ends with a vowel in a *case insensitive* way ([*`REGEXP` is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp))

  - `^` - matches the start of input
  - `[AEIOU]` - a single vowel from the set
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible (POSIX regex used in MySQL does not support lazy quantifiers, and `.` matches any chars, even line break chars, too)
  - `[AEIOU]` - a vowel
  - `$` - end of input.

Comment: Sorry for edits, I have not drunk my morning coffee yet :)

Comment: `LIKE` use `%` rather than `*`,

Comment: @JacquesAmar Yeah, not only, I am still a bit asleep.

Comment: :-) I'm on the other side of the planet, falling asleep. Just a though, but maybe offer `[AEIOUaeiou]`

Comment: @JacquesAmar Actually, `REGEXP` matching in MySQL is case insensitive by default. `BINARY` keyword makes it case sensitive. See [this reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp): *REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.*

Comment: Thanks, I actually learned something new before going to sleep!

Comment: Thank you for including the city named `Å` in Norway.

Answer (score 0):

^ : Match the beginning of a string.and $ : Match the end of a string.
so  you can try with above both regex and also  use % , may be helpful.

Comment: One can't mix wildcard with regex patterns, a `%` char used with `REGEXP` will only match a literal `%`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ,Thanks for clarification.